# Calling a callback function that returns a setTimeOut callback javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, callback, settimeout

I tried searching for this, but was unable to find something that matched the case I needed.

I have this function here that can't be modified:

```
function generate() {
  const delay = 7000 + Math.random() * 7000;
  const num = Math.random();

  return (callback) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      callback(num);
    }, delay);
  };
}
```

When I try to call the function like `generate()` I get an error. I've also tried using a promise based approach like:

```
    const result = await generate();
    return result;
```

But when I do that the result that is returned is a promise, which I can't render into JSX (I'm using React).

JSX component code (For debugging purposes currently):

```
const Test = () => { 
return <>{generate()}</>;
};
```

I would appreciate any suggestions here. Thanks!

Comment: What was the error? What is the `generate` function?

Comment: Sounds like you want to `return new Promise(generate())`?

Comment: "*I can't render into JSX (I'm using React).*" - please show us that code if it's the one that is not working. (You might not even need promises or async/await with react!) Also it seems like you dropped the first line of the `generate` function code

Answer (score 0):

This in no way is to solve your problem, but only to understand this logic. Maybe it can help in solving the problem.

generate() in this case returns a function that sets the timeout.

```
   typeof generate() = "function"
  // this is then the function we use to run the long running function

  const generateFunction = generate();

  //we then create the callback handler function
  const callback = () =>  {...}
  //when executed it will set the timeout to the random delay and display the result in your component of oyur choice.
  generateFunction(callback);
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2d1q3we6/)